# Search text on locked layers

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, layers

I just "discovered" that search (note: I talk about search, not replace!) doesn't work for text on locked layers.

Some people suggest to enable "Include Locked Layers and Locked Objects" and "Include Locked Stories" options to workaround this issue, but this solution doesn't work for; neither for Anne-Marie, co-founder and CEO of Creative Publishing Network, creativepro.com, see the discussion here: https://creativepro.com/topic/indesign-cs5-question-finding-a-text-in-locked-text-frame-79/

[image]

I use CS6. The issue might have been fixed in newer versions, but I don't really know. Is it so?

And are there any workarounds (except for using GREP instead of normal search)?

Comment: erm.. can't one make the layers visible and perform the search, then turn off visibility again? The layer visibility toggle is global for the document.

Comment: @Scott Of course, this is a possible workaround. But I'm wondering are there any other ones :) And sorry, actually I assumed locked layers rather than hidden ones; I've corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew this should work, and tried again in my CC version. Created a text box with the text "XXX" included, layer **locked**, searched with the `Include Locked Layers` and it seems to find it.

I have also **hidden** that layer and with the `Include Hidden Layers` option, it can still find it.

[image]

Comment: Well, yes, I got the same message, sorry for not being clear enough. What I mean is that InDesign doesn't select the found text for you. The window that simply says that searched text exists (somewhere) is barely useful, in my opinion...

Comment: If you hide the layer, it actually DOES select the text and then if you UNHIDE the layer, the text remains selected.

Comment: Yes, but I don't care about hidden layers. The subject of my interest is how is it possible to search text on **locked** layers.

Comment: @jsv I don't think it's possible. The dilemma is that InDesign highlights found text but selecting it but you can't make a selection in locked objects.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, you can search in both locked and hidden layers. However the search results ONLY get selected/highlighted on HIDDEN layers.

Comment: OK, so I mark this answer as correct (although the task is impossible)

Comment: Correct, the task is impossible.